# Using mpivars.sh with set -e option

Tags: mpi

I am trying to discover `set -x` and `set -e` options with `mpivars.sh`. I think the problem, which appears to me, is in `mpivars.sh`.

Could you, please, show the correct result in using like this: `set -e -x; . ./mpivars.sh`? Am I right?

So, the main mistake is:

```
When: $ set -e -x; . ./mpivars.sh
It  says: Connection to machinename closed.
```

Why does it throw me away from a machine?
Because as for `help set` it says that: `Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.`

I'd just like to know which correct output is actually.

Comment: If you are using IntelMPI, then you should `. ./mpivars.sh` instead

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet   Yes, you are right. I did it in this way, it is just my mistake in writting.

Comment: Try to `set -e` __after__ sourcing `./ mpivars.sh`. I do not thing anything guarantees __all__ the commands in `mpivars.sh` have to success, so it could be erroneous to `set -e`.

Comment: `false; if test $? -eq 0; then echo TRUE; else echo FALSE; fi` this is a textbook example that does not print anything when `set -e` is used.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet   thank you for help. I have decided the problem.